# How to plot a complex valued function showing a non-conformal mapping in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have the function:

```
f(z) = conj(z) + 0.4*z^2,
```

Going from a polar grid where `0 < theta < 2pi` and between `0.5 < |z| < 2.5` for its two radii. I have no idea where to start as I'm new to MATLAB but I'm trying to make 2 subplots each with two parametric equations for each curve but I've had no success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Swap the definition of `f` to switch between the polar grid and the transformed grid. I also answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53472184/how-to-plot-the-wolfram-alpha-grid-matlab/).

```
clear
clc

N = 41;
t = linspace(0, 2*pi, N);
r = linspace(0.5, 2.5, N);
[R,T] = meshgrid(r,t);

Z = R.*exp(T*1i);

% f = Z; %Original mesh
f = conj(Z) + 0.4*Z.^2; %Transformed mesh

U = real(f);
V = imag(f);

%Plot mesh
hold off
plot(U,V,'b-');
hold on
plot(U',V','r-');

xlim([-5,5]);
ylim([-5,5]);
axis equal
```